# constant deviation projecting lat lon to itm(israel tranverse mercator

Tags: open-source-gis, coordinate-system, proj

i use two different ways to project lat lon data taken from google earth to ITM (Israel Transverse Mercator) and export the data to arcmap 
 same ways i try to unproject ITM data and export the data to google earth
 both ways i get a deviation of about 90 m

 first way: cs2c2 
 - 
  `cs2cs +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 +lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.000007 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m file.txt>output.txt` 
second way: DNRgarmin : i downloaded DNRgarmin open a shp file or a kml file and try to convert it

both ways i get a deviation of about 90m does anyone have an idea wht i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly need to add a datum transformation to the cs2cs definition. I would try

```
+towgs84=-48,55,52
```

which is listed as having approximately 2m accuracy in the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](http://www.epsg-registry.org). Another possibility is the following, but I am not sure of its provenance (including its accuracy):

```
+towgs84=24.0024,17.1032,17.8444,-0.33009,-1.85269,1.66969,-5.4248
```

Note: ITM uses the Israel GeogCRS (aka datum) which is based upon the GRS80 ellipsoid, but that doesn't mean that the Israel datum is the same as WGS84.

Comment: and when i am transforming the other way, from ITM to lanlon?

Comment: It should still work because the transformation is defined as being from "other" datum to WGS84. The software will know how to apply when transforming from WGS84.